# How to save and use multiple lines?

Tags: python

In a recent challenge I was given a number of tasks to write some code, one of which was to capture each "item code" listed in a csv file. However, I wasn't given a file to read from, instead someone cut and pasted a few excerpts in to the same notebook that I was being asked to live code in. I don't remember the exact details of the data, it was something like this:

```
# row #   id,     item code,     account,   period,   location
# 1:   idswam1,  754527542,    a396,          3,          IR
# 2:   cbskuf5,  986435614,    a952,          9,          CH
...
```

Now, in python how would I capture the above data? If it was in a file I could use pandas read_csv, but given that they have listed the data as commented fields within the same notebook. I'm tasked with processing it, but what's the most effective way to process this? thoughts I had:

1. Is this a multi-line string? Or should I be saving each row number in a separate variable before I start processing it?
2. Given that I can't escape out of this notebook, how would should I treat the data if it is strings, comma separated or something else?

note, I can't escape the notebook to save the data as a file.

Comment: "I don't remember the exact details of the data" Then how are we supposed to answer questions like "Is this a multi-line string?" It either was or it wasn't, depending on those exact details. Anyway, it seems like your question isn't really about Python, but about the environment provided by Jupyter. (You should at least make sure that you understand the technologies you're using. "Notebooks" *don't* come from the language, and also Pandas is a third-party library.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a multiline string:

1. `io.StringIO` to read the string as a 'file'
2. `read_csv` with a regex for the separator
3. Drop the first column coming from the '#' at the beginning of the lines

```
import io
import pandas as pd

testdata = """
# row #   id,     item code,     account,   period,   location
# 1:   idswam1,  754527542,    a396,          3,          IR
# 2:   cbskuf5,  986435614,    a952,          9,          CH
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(testdata), sep=r"\s*[#,:]\s*")
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

```
   row       id  item code account  period location
0    1  idswam1  754527542    a396       3       IR
1    2  cbskuf5  986435614    a952       9       CH
```